# How can I fix this woocommerce cart update problem?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart, hook-woocommerce

I have problem with the cart update. When I remove all (and the last) item, the "Cart Totals" box is still visible. I can not find any solution for this problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: Share site url please

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick way to remove the cart totals, you could unhook the `woocommerce_cart_totals` function from the `woocommerce_cart_collaterals` hook!

```
<?php
// functions.php

remove_action('woocommerce_cart_totals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10);
// ^ keep the same priority of 10 to unhook reliably.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to show the cart totals. My problem is when I remove all item in the cart, totals is still visible. It is not disappearing. Disappearing when I refresh the cart page.